# Is there a way to return both StatusCode and Content in a HttpRequest?

Tags: c#, http, xamarin, model-view-controller, webapi

I have got a login page in my app, which makes a request to the WebAPI that should return a StatusCode **Accepted** when the credentials match the database record, but I would also like it to return some data about the user for usage further in the app so I don't have to request them every time I need it. Is there a way to return both StatusCode and some content from the database record with a single **return** statement?

The API part which returns the StatusCode looks like this:

```
reader = checkCredentials.ExecuteReader();
            reader.Read();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                reader.Close();
                return Accepted();
            }
            else
            {
                reader.Close();
                return Unauthorized();
            }
```

How can I change it?

Answer (score 0):

```
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, "{yourdata}");
```

or

```
Response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Accepted;
return Content("{yourdata}");
```

Comment: @Wurfv_ 202 implying that the request is just accepted not executed, in your case its also executed so you should return 200 as successful execution result.

Comment: + I like the add a little System.Net.HttpStatusCode enum in the status code place for more readability

Comment: Shouldn't it just be a normal response without the statuscode? Because 200 will always be returned.